# Running Some Tests Sequentially While Others in Parallel

Tags: unit-testing, testing, parallel-processing, rust, automated-tests

I have several tests:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn foo() {
        // Must be run sequentially
    }

    #[test]
    fn bar() {
        // Must be run sequentially.
    }

    #[test]
    fn baz() {
        // Can be run in parallel.
    }

    #[test]
    fn qux() {
        // Can be run in parallel.
    }
}
```

`foo()` and `bar()` must be run sequentially, because they might race with themselves or another test not shown.

I can prevent a race condition by only using one thread to test, `cargo test -- --test-threads=1`. But I don't want to do this because I'd like `baz()` and `qux()` to be run in parallel.

I could also place the `#[ignore]` attribute on `foo()` and `bar()`. Call `cargo test` to invoke `baz()` and `qux()` in parallel, then just individually run `foo()` and `bar()`, but that is a lot of work.

Is there any way to ensure that `foo()` and `bar()` run sequentially, but all other tests run in parallel with a single invocation of `cargo test`? For reference [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html) are the current attributes.

Comment: Can't you just use a `Mutex`?